# Какой linux установить?

Tags: дистрибутив, linux

В глаза не видел unix систем и в жизни ни одну из них не устанавливал. На работе только с FreeBSD по SSH. Но у них же и GUI есть. Подскажите какой дистрибутив выбрать? Машина мощная, по-этому с ресурсами ограничений нет никаких абсолютно. Главное чтобы всё было просто и понятно для человека, который кроме винды ничего не видел) Заранее спасибо.

UPD. На систему нужно будет установить JDK для разработки на java. веб-сервер (apache скорее всего), php, MySQL сервер. То есть ставить буду не ради интереса, а для того чтобы разрабатывать приложения.

Comment: Комментарий для уважаемого @ХэшКод.

-

Активность на РутКод низкая. Я задавал некоторое время назад аналогичный вопрос там и здесь. 

Разница в активности отвечающих различается просто на порядок.

Comment: А админ FreeBSD не разрешает X'ы? А то туннелирование X11 через SSH -- штука отработанная, и со свободными Xserver'ами под винды сейчас никаких проблем.

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как вопроса не по теме, потому что слишком стар для переноса

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если выбирать,то надо исходить из некоторых условий:

1. Опыт работы на компьютере
2. Усидчивость
3. Ближайшее окружение

Поясню, если опыт работы на компе не ограничивается лишь запуском игрушки,  калькулятора и общения в "Одноклассниках", то вероятность освоить - высока, хотя в случае с играми, то сейчас такие игры с защитой, что требуют огромных усилий и танцами, чтобы поставить её. Усидчивость нужна всегда, спешка нужна лишь при ловле блох, но самое главное - это окружение, если есть знакомые, у которых стоит Linux и они не против помогать в ближайшее время, то ставь тот дистрибутив, что и них, если нет таких - то не спеша, полазь по сети, посмотри на форумы, обрати внимание на количество тем, время откликов на созданные темы, качество ответов и определись, где для тебя понятны ответы и решения, то тот и ставь, не понравиться - снесешь и поставишь другое, делов-то!

Answer (score 2):

Ставь убунту, только рекомендую 11.04 , поскольку у него есть возможность поставить нормальный GNOME 2, у 11.10 такая возможность уже отсутствует, а Unity и GNOME 3 никому не посоветую ((((. Или еще можно попробовать Xubuntu - ее рабочий стол Xfce - очень приятная и перспективная вещь.

Comment: установил как раз 11.10. Что-то честно скажу не вдохновляет. Может потому что она только устанавливается. И по какой-то неизвестной науке причине не видит 2й монитор. Шрифты другие какие-то. Забавно вообщем. Так и неясно почему линуксоиды не любят винду=)

Comment: Я тут поставил под VirtualBox на Windows ubuntu 10.04 дома и xubuntu 11.4 на работе. Рабочий стол Xfce и файловый менеджер Thunar на xubuntu больше понравились, а вот эмулятор терминала в Gnome (ubuntu) лучше, т.к. позволяет выбирать кодировку русского языка.

В целом (для разработки) разницы не ощущается, общая оценка - все замечательно.

Ubunu 11.10 с Unity тоже попробовал и через пару часов снес (из-за организации графического интерфейса).

Comment: Зашел снова в винду и снова всё привычно и родное будто) linux штука может и интересная. Но пока что многое неясно. Например что там за репозиторий такой необъятный, откуда всё можно установить.. забавно)

Comment: Мне gnome-terminal тоже больше нравится. Кстати, его можно запросто поставить и под Xubuntu. Thunar мне не очень,  Nautilus кажется более удобным.

Comment: В Thunar-е мне нравится то, что в любом каталоге (отображаемом в его окне, в т.ч. текущем) можно запустить терминал. Все остальное (что приходит в голову использовать) в принципе у него с Nautilus-ом IMHO одинаково.

--

Репозиторий - это установка по apt-get ?  Удобно. Вообще линукс хорош тем, что если что-то не ставится, то можно скачать исходники и собрать самому (вбить пинками в конце концов). В винде такое редко проходит.

Comment: вообще linux оказывается штука комфортная. Разобрался с репозиториями. А по поводу "собрать самому" пока что не приходилось. За 2 дня в винду ниразу не заглянул) Единственная проблема - звук. У меня система 5.1 и наушники с микрофоном. Хотелось бы чтоб при включении ушей, звук на 5.1 отключался. ХЗ как сделать. Всю сеть перерыл так и не нашел ничего=\

Comment: Боюсь, что никак. ((( Только кнопочкой на системе. Но меня лично это не сильно напрягает.  )))

Comment: Welcome to the Wonderland

Answer (score 1):

ubuntu проще всего для новичка, имхо.

Answer (score 0):

любой.. из флагманов ubuntu, fedora, opensuse

Comment: у них установка чем-то отличается от установки win7? или впринципе то же самое?

Comment: отличается.

http://linuxgid.ru/category/ustanovka-i-rabota/ustanovka-linux/
http://it-talk.ru/?p=317
http://ikherson.com/blog-1231.html

Answer (score 0):

Можно скачать Debian

В этом дистрибутиве есть практически любая подручная программа и качать из нета пакеты не нужно просто ставишь диск и устанавливаешь прогу.

Так же ставится просто.

Ну или Fedora.

Я предпочитаю эти 2 Linuxa.

Debian стоит серваком на Fedorой работаю.